# Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function bold automatic the tabele from javascript

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

Hello everyone I want to insert into my wordpress this code
my CSS and JavaScript are all in this link but it shows me this error when I insert in wordpress. I do not know what I'm doing wrong
http://jsfiddle.net/sah27uo6/4/   in http://jsfiddle.net/ works great but when I insert in wordpress it does not work

```html
<tbody><table width="100%" style="
    mergin-top: 10px;
    line-height: 5px;
"> 

<tr>
<td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">11:15</td>
<td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">CUFE-REISEN</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">11:30</td>
<td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">AZIZI</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">11:45</td>
<td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">ENDRITI</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">12:00</td>
<td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">DRITONI-REIS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">12:15</td>
<td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">METI-COMERC</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">12:30</td>
<td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">ENDRITI</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">12:45</td>
<td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">BLERI-COMER</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">13:00</td>
<td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">ARBENI-TOURS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">13:15</td>
<td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">ARBENI-TOURS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">13:30</td>
<td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">AZIZI</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">13:45</td>
<td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">ENDRITI</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">14:00</td>
<td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">ENDRITI</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">14:15</td>
<td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">MEDINA</td>
</tr>


</table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="...../boldrajonal.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..../ngjyra.css">
    </tbody>
```

```js
var hour = new Date().getHours() + 1;

$('table td:nth-child(1)').each(function (index, td) {
    if ($(td).text().indexOf(hour) == 0) {
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass('highlight-time');
    } else {
        $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('highlight-time');
    }
});
```

```css
.highlight-time {
    font-weight: bold;
    color:blue;
}
```

```html
<tbody>
    <table width="100%" style="
    mergin-top: 10px;
    line-height: 5px;
">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">NGA:</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;"><strong>Prishtina</strong>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">NË:</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;"><strong>Ferizaj</strong>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">Qmimi</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">: <strong>1,50€</strong>  (Euro)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">Student</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">: <strong>1,00€</strong>  (Euro)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">NISJA</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">OPERATORI</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">06:45</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">BLERI-COM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">07:45</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">ENDRITI</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">08:00</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">BEKA-KAQANIK</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">08:15</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">MEDINA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">08:30</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">METI-COMERC</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">08:45</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">ARBENI-TOURS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">09:00</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">DRITONI-REIS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">09:15</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">ENDRITI</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">09:30</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">DRITONI-REIS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">09:45</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">BLERI-COMER</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">10:00</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">BALLKANI</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">10:15</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">ENDRITI</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">10:30</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">ARBENI</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">10:45</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">FEHMI-COM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">11:00</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">FATIONI-REISEN</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">11:15</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">CUFE-REISEN</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">11:30</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">AZIZI</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">11:45</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">ENDRITI</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">12:00</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">DRITONI-REIS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">12:15</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">METI-COMERC</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">12:30</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">ENDRITI</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">12:45</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">BLERI-COMER</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">13:00</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">ARBENI-TOURS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">13:15</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">ARBENI-TOURS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">13:30</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">AZIZI</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">13:45</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">ENDRITI</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">14:00</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">ENDRITI</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">14:15</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">MEDINA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">14:30</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">DRITONI-REIS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">14:45</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">BEKA-KAQANIK</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">15:00</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">DRITONI-REIS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">15:15</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">ARBENI</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">15:30</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">ENDRITI</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">15:45</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">BLERI-COM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">16:00</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">FEHMI-COM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">16:15</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">FEHMI-COM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">16:30</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">ENDRITI</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">16:45</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">CUFA-REIS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">17:00</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">AZIZI</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">17:15</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">DRITONI-REIS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">17:30</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">ENDRITI</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">17:45</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">ARBENI-TU</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">18:00</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">MEDINA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">18:15</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">BLERI-COMERC</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">18:30</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">BLERI-COMERC</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">18:45</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">BALLKANI</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">19:00</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">ENDRITI</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">19:15</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">FEHMI-COM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">19:30</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">FATONI-REISEN</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">19:45</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">ENDRITI-KAQANIK</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">20:00</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">ENDRITI</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">20:15</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">ENDRITI</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">20:30</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">FEHMI-COM</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</tbody>
```

Comment: have you included `jquery.js`?

Comment: Yes but I have to add so only how it works there

<script type="text/javascript" src="...../boldrajonal.js"></script>

Comment: the well  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..../ngjyra.css">

Comment: Make sure that your javascript is after the script tag for jQuery (have a look at the ordering in the dev tools to check this).

Comment: Thank you for your info .es works great. with info from rnevius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is included with WordPress by default [in no-conflict mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers). In `noConflict()` mode, the global `$` shortcut for jQuery is not available, so you need to use something like the following to make it available to you:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
    // and other libraries also using $ will not be accessible under this shortcut
});
```

Alternatively, replace the `$` shortcut with `jQuery`:

```
jQuery('table td:nth-child(1)').each(function (index, td) {
    if (jQuery(td).text().indexOf(hour) == 0) {
        jQuery(this).closest('tr').addClass('highlight-time');
    } else {
        jQuery(this).closest('tr').removeClass('highlight-time');
    }
});
```